# Form Web Part to Excel Sheet - MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, data-form-web-part, list-form-web-part

You'll have to excuse my amateur-ness as I am very new to Sharepoint. I have created a form which I will eventually want multiple people to fill out. I was hoping the data will update an excel spreadsheet which I have uploaded. I have connected the form web part to an Excel Web Access web part if this is the correct method.

Any help would be gratefully received,